# htaccess rewrite ignore 2 strings

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule to rewrite my old to new URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/activity.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)/$ /$1/S$2/ [R=301,L]
```

It must also ignore /members, not only /activity.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you thought about just adding another `RewriteCond` directive? (`^/activity.*$` is the same as simply `^/activity` - the last `.*$` is not required.)

Comment: tbh, I did not know that I can stack them... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can just add another `RewriteCond` directive:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/activity
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/members
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)/$ /$1/S$2/ [R=301,L]
```

Multiple `RewriteCond` directives are AND'd together by default. The `OR` flag can be used if required. I've removed the `NC` flag - unless you specifically need a case-insensitive match. As mentioned in comments, I've also simplified your regex slightly. `.*$` says that the string can have any characters after the word "/activity", which is the same as a string that is simply prefixed with "/activity".

Comment: Oh, I somehow missed your explanation about the `.*$`, which was the reason for my post. +1 for you, I'm keeping mine for the OR option :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by adding another condition.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/members [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/activity [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)/$ /$1/S$2/ [R=301,L]
```

Or, sometimes simpeler, use the OR of a regex:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(members|activity) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)/$ /$1/S$2/ [R=301,L]
```

---

I've removed the `.*$` from your lines. That piece ment "any character (`.*`) untill the end (`$`) of the line. By removing that, you get the exact same effect, but more readable and I'm guessing it requires less resources because the regex is simpler.